# Switch control both light and outlet

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch, receptacle

In the en-suite bathroom, there is a switch (1 of 3) that controls the main overhead light and the outlet. Is there anyway to get the outlet to have constant power? Or is this one of those jobs that are easier said than done???

The house was built in 1978, I currently do not have pictures but could easily provide some this evening.

Yes, this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156289/remove-single-pole-switch-that-control-outlet) is similar but with mine being a bathroom I would also like to know if there is anything else I should be aware of (e.g. adding a GFCI outlet)???

Comment: Sure there is. _What_ it is depends on how it's wired, about which we know nothing. Did you have a more specific question.

Comment: Without opening the boxes for the switch, the light, and the outlet, any answer is just going to be a guess or general wiring information.  The key is getting a "constant hot" to the outlet rather than a "switched hot", and in some configurations that's as easy as moving a wire connection.  In other cases, it means pulling new wire.  Is this a single story house?

Comment: Cool - in response to both the above comments. I will post photos when I get home this evening.

Comment: @JCrosby, pictures are good - turn power off before opening the boxes and don't unhook anything without knowing how to put it back exactly the way you found it.  One big issue we have is people unhooking wires _then_ asking where the wires should go.

Comment: @JPhi1618, I appreciate the word of caution! While my experience with electrical is limited to changing fixtures, standard wall outlets, and one dimmer switch - I do my best to use safe practices (turn off at the breaker, double check with a "tester-pen", etc.)

Comment: If you stick a GFCI tester in the outlet and push "test", does a GFCI trip somewhere?

Comment: @Harper,never considered that. Like the above comments I will do that and report back when I post the pictures.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please?

Answer (score 1):

Typically A 1/2 Switched outlet is broken in the middle of the tab between the two screws. If the one outlet is always powered, there is constant power to that outlet and the other outlet is connected to the switch leg of the light switch.  If this is the case, then that outlet should already have a GFCI on it. If not, then you can replace the outlet with the GFCI but you want to be sure that the Switched 1/2 of the outlet is capped off, Taped and Labeled in the Box.

Pictures are also Wonderful to see. (-;